# New Object PSCredential not working - using Unicode punctuation syntactically

Tags: powershell, unicode, utf-8, punctuation

I'm trying to accept username and password as params to a Powershell script but the new-Object

```
$UserID="Name"
$SecurePassword=convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force -String $Password
New-object –TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –ArgumentList ($UserID,$SecurePassword)
```

Gives an error

> New-object : Cannot find type [â€TypeName
>   System.Management.Automation.PSCredential â€ArgumentList]: verify that
>   the as sembly containing this type is loaded. At C:\ps\login.ps1:14
>   char:17
>   + ... rCredential=New-object â€“TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCre ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Anybody got some clues how to solve this?

Comment: The `–` in front of `ArgumentList` is not a hyphen, but an EN dash (U+2013), replace it with a hyphen (`-`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `–` in front of the `TypeName` and `ArgumentList` parameters are not hyphens, but EN dashes (U+2013), and this trips up the parser. Replace them with a hyphen (`-`):

```
'New-object –TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –ArgumentList ($UserID,$SecurePassword)' -replace '\p{Pd}','-'
```

`\p{Pd}` is the unicode class for "**P**unctuation, **d**ashes"

<sup>**Editor's note**: PowerShell, perhaps surprisingly, does *not* have a problem with using `–` (en dash) in lieu of the regular ASCII-range `-` ("dash", technically: *hyphen-minus*) - try `Get-ChildItem –File`, for instance.

**The OP's only problem is a *character-encoding* one, which you happen to *bypass* if you convert to regular "dashes".
Turning the Unicode en dashes into ASCII "dashes" is only a *stopgap***: It masks the OP's true problem of having saved a file with an encoding that Windows PowerShell misinterprets. If that file contained non-ASCII characters as *data*, it would still be broken.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

**PowerShell is unusual in that allows *interchangeable use* of *ASCII-range punctuation and whitespace* with (non-ASCII) *Unicode punctuation and whitespace*** - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55053609/45375) for a complete list of characters.

Therefore, use of non-ASCII character `–` EN DASH (`U+2013`) in lieu of ASCII character `-` HYPHEN-MINUS (`U+002D`) is *not* a problem in itself.

The problem in your case was a ***character encoding* problem**, as evidenced by your error output: the en dashes weren't recognized as such, because - as you've later stated in a comment - **your source code file was UTF-8-encoded *but lacked a BOM***, causing PowerShell to interpret it as "ANSI" code page-encoded (e.g., code page Windows-1252 on US-English systems).

This misinterpretation causes `–` to be interpreted as `â€`, and that is the true cause of your problem.

**Using UTF-8 to save your source code is generally a good idea, but on *Windows PowerShell* you *must include a BOM*.**
That said, if your source code *happens not to* contain any non-ASCII characters, there won't be a problem.

Generally, the BOM requirement is at odds with UTF-8 use on other platforms, where a BOM may even cause problems (but not in PowerShell); perhaps for that reason **modern editors such as Visual Studio Code and Sublime Text default to *BOM-less* UTF-8 and must explicitly be instructed to save *with* a BOM**; while you can typically change the default to including a BOM, it is best to do that only for PowerShell files, if supported.

Note that PowerShell *Core* doesn't have this problem, as it *defaults* to UTF-8 (but still correctly recognizes a UTF-8 BOM, if present).