# PowerShell script runs when pasted into the PowerShell window, but not when run from shortcut

Tags: powershell, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, codepages

I am trying to put together a script that will convert several Excel files into PDF files. [I found a link to one online that works](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/save-a-microsoft-excel-workbook-as-a-pdf-file-by-using-powershell/).

```
$path = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input Directory Path and Press Enter'
$xlFixedFormat = “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType” -as [type]
$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -include *.xls, *.xlsx -recurse
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$objExcel.visible = $false
foreach($wb in $excelFiles)
{
    $filepath = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ($wb.BaseName + “.pdf”)
    $workbook = $objExcel.workbooks.open($wb.fullname, 3)
    $workbook.Saved = $true
    “saving $filepath”
    $workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat($xlFixedFormat::xlTypePDF, $filepath)
    $objExcel.Workbooks.close()
}
$objExcel.Quit()
```

If I copy and paste this into a PowerShell window, the program runs as intended. However, when I attempted to make a shortcut to run the program, I get several errors (the file is saved as a .ps1).

This is the path and arguments I made when setting up the shortcut:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\[File Path]
```

This is the error message I get:

```
At C:\Users\cbeals.ENVIROTECH\Documents\Test\ConvertExcelToPDF.ps1:8 char:62
+  $filepath = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ($wb.BaseName + â€œ.pdf ...
+                                                              ~
You must provide a value expression following the '+' operator.
At C:\Users\cbeals.ENVIROTECH\Documents\Test\ConvertExcelToPDF.ps1:8 char:63
+ ... lepath = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ($wb.BaseName + â€œ.pdfâ€)
+                                                               ~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'â€œ.pdfâ€' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\cbeals.ENVIROTECH\Documents\Test\ConvertExcelToPDF.ps1:8 char:62
+  $filepath = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ($wb.BaseName + â€œ.pdf ...
+                                                              ~
Missing closing ')' in expression.
At C:\Users\cbeals.ENVIROTECH\Documents\Test\ConvertExcelToPDF.ps1:7 char:1
+ {
+ ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At C:\Users\cbeals.ENVIROTECH\Documents\Test\ConvertExcelToPDF.ps1:8 char:73
+ ... lepath = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ($wb.BaseName + â€œ.pdfâ€)
+                                                                         ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\cbeals.ENVIROTECH\Documents\Test\ConvertExcelToPDF.ps1:14 char:1
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

Why would this be failing?

Comment: What program did you use to save it as a .ps1 file? I copied it from your answer, pasted it into Notepad and saved it and it ran just fine.  The error message indicates it's not interpreting the quotes around ".pdf" correctly, which seems like it would be a file encoding issue of some sort.  Try copying from your answer here, opening notepad, pasting it and saving it again.

Comment: You are using typographic quotes above, change to normal single `'` or double `"` quotes.

Comment: @kpogue, this fixed it. I had initally used Notepad++ to save it. As you suggested, I saved it as a .ps1 using standard notepad and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

To clarify:

- **It is perfectly fine to use Unicode (non-ASCII-range) quotation marks such as [`“`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm) in PowerShell** - see the bottom section.
- However, in order to use such characters in *script files*, these **files must use a *Unicode* character encoding** such as UTF-8 or UTF-16LE ("Unicode").

Your problem was that **your script file was saved as UTF-8 *without a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)*, which causes *Windows PowerShell* (but *not* [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)) to *misinterpret* it**, because it **defaults to "ANSI" encoding**, i.e., the single-byte legacy encoding associated with the legacy system locale a.k.a language for non-Unicode programs (e.g., [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) in the US and Western Europe), which PowerShell calls `Default`.

While replacing the Unicode quotation marks with their ASCII counterparts solves the immediate problem, any other non-ASCII-range characters in the script would continue to be misinterpreted.

- The **proper solution is to re-save the file as UTF-8 *with BOM*.**
- It is a good habit to form to **routinely save all PowerShell scripts (source code) as UTF-8 *with BOM***, because that ensures that they're interpreted the same, irrespective of any given computer's *system locale* (culture), and irrespective of what *PowerShell edition* you use.

  - See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54790355/45375), which shows how to configure **Visual Studio Code** to create new PowerShell files as UTF-8 *with BOM*.

---

To demonstrate the specific problem:

- `“`, the LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK (`U+201C`) Unicode character, is encoded as *three* bytes in UTF-8 format: `0xE2 0x80 0x9C`.
- You can verify this via the output from `'“' | Format-Hex -Encoding Utf8` (only the byte sequence matters here; the printed characters. on the right are not representative in this case).
- When Windows PowerShell reads this sequence as "ANSI"-encoded, it considers *each byte a character in its own right*, which is why you saw *three* characters for the single `“` in your output, namely `â€œ`.
- You can verify this with `[Text.Encoding]::Default.GetString([byte[]] (0xE2, 0x80, 0x9C))` (from PowerShell *Core*, use `[Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding([cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage).GetString([byte[]] (0xE2, 0x80, 0x9C))`).

---

#### Interchangeable use of ASCII-range and Unicode quotation marks, dashes, and [whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) in PowerShell:

In a properly encoded input file, PowerShell allows interchangeable use of the following quotation and punctuation characters; e.g., `"hi"`, `”hi”` and even `"hi„` are equivalent.

- **Double quotes**:

  - `"` (ASCII-range) - [QUOTATION MARK (`U+0022`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22/index.htm)
  - `“` - [LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK (`U+201C`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm)
  - `”` - [RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK (`U+201D`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm)
  - `„` - [DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK (`U+201E`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201e/index.htm)
  - But **not**: `‟` - [DOUBLE HIGH-REVERSED-9 QUOTATION MARK (`U+201F`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201f), even though its single-quote counterpart *is* recognized - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9502).
- **Single quotes**:

  - `'` - (ASCII-range) [APOSTROPHE (`U+0027`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27/index.htm)
  - `‘` - [LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (`U+2018`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2018/index.htm)
  - `’` - [RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (`U+2019`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm)
  - `‚` - [SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK (`U+201A`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201a/index.htm)
  - `‛` - [SINGLE HIGH-REVERSED-9 QUOTATION MARK (`U+201B`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201b/index.htm)
- **Dashes** (strictly speaking, the ASCII-range "dash" is a *hyphen*):

  - `-` (ASCII-range) - [HYPHEN-MINUS (`U+002D`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm)
  - `–` - [EN DASH (`U+2013`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm)
  - `—` - [EM DASH (`U+2014`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm)
  - `―` - [HORIZONTAL BAR (`U+2015`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2015/index.htm)
- **Whitespace**:

  - Note: The source-code location linked to below doesn't define equivalent whitespace characters explicitly (unlike quotation marks and dashes). The following was gleaned from experiments based on Unicode character descriptions and may be incomplete.  Characters outside the Unicode BMP (basic multilingual plane), i.e. those with code point that won't fit into the 16-bit code units .NET uses to represent characters, were excluded.
  - ***Intra-line* whitespace**:

    - Note: Space-character and tab-character variations can interchangeably serve as syntactic word separators. Among the space-character variations, only the `U+200B` ([ZERO WIDTH SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm)) character is *not* considered a space syntactically.
    - Spaces:

      - (ASCII-range space character) `U+0020` ([SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20/index.htm))
      - `U+00A0` ([NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm))
      - `U+2002` ([EN SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2002/index.htm))
      - `U+2003` ([EM SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2003/index.htm))
      - `U+2004` ([THREE-PER-EM SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2004/index.htm))
      - `U+2005` ([FOUR-PER-EM SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2005/index.htm)))
      - `U+2006` ([SIX-PER-EM SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2006/index.htm))
      - `U+2007` ([FIGURE SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2007/index.htm))
      - `U+2008` ([PUNCTUATION SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2008/index.htm))
      - `U+2009` ([THIN SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2009/index.htm))
      - `U+200A` ([HAIR SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200a/index.htm))
      - `U+202F` ([NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202f/index.htm))
      - `U+205F` ([MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/205f/index.htm))
      - `U+3000` ([IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3000/index.htm))
    - Tabulators (shown as escape sequences due to not being directly printable  here):

      - `` "`t" `` (ASCII-range tab character) - `U+0009` ([CHARACTER TABULATION](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/9/index.htm))
      - `` "`v" `` (ASCII-range vertical-tab character) - `U+000B` ([LINE TABULATION](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b/index.htm)))
  - ***Line-separating* whitespace**:

    - (ASCII-range LF) `U+000A` ([LINE FEED](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a/index.htm))
    - (ASCII-range CR) `U+000D` ([CARRIAGE RETURN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d/index.htm))

Note:

- **Important**: The above **describes interchangeable *syntactic* use of these characters**; if you use such characters in *identifiers* (which you shouldn't) or in *strings*<sup>[1]</sup>, they are *not* treated the same.
- The above was in part gleaned [from the source code on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/3547acaa1ca9e1141cf1f7d4725c045285618911/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/parser/CharTraits.cs#L235-L282) (Functions `Is...` in file `CharTraits.cs`, also see above for `SpecialChars` definition).

---

<sup>[1] There are limited exceptions: given that PowerShell's `-eq` operator compares string using the *invariant culture* rather than performing *ordinal* comparison, *space-character* variations *may* be treated the same in string comparisons, *depending on the host platform*; e.g., `` "foo bar" -eq "foo`u{a0}bar" `` yields `$true` on macOS and Linux (but not Windows!), because the regular ASCII-range space is considered equal to the no-break space (`U+00A0`) there.</sup>