# Running sh script with a bat script

Tags: powershell

I am using a script to send emails on my machine , the script is a sh script and i need to execute automatically that script via another batch script , the problem is when i copy past the code on my Powershell command directly the code works fine the email will be sent , but then when I try to use a script to run it it always fail :
This is my code for email :

```
$EmailFrom = “whatever@gmail.com” 
'$EmailTo = “whatever@gmail.com”
'$Subject = “helooo2o”
$Body = “test test test”
$SMTPServer = “smtp.gmail.com”
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential(“whatever@gmail.com”, “pwd”);
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
```

it works fine when i put it directly on CMD then Powershell it works but when i use this script
it won't work :

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe  -windowstyle hidden -command 'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test.sh'
```

also when I use PowerShell with the command : Bash test.sh it shows me this :

```
bash /test.sh: cannot execute binary file
```

Can you guys help me i need to run automatically this script with a batch script thank you in advance .

Comment: What you have above has nothing to do with BASH or SH. Is there any other reason you have included those two tags? The syntax between powershell and Linux bash/sh is completely different. Bash and sh work with ASCII text in at most UTF-8 encoding. I suspect your file is in UTF-16.

Comment: hello thank you for ur reply , but i just checked with my notepad ++ in the buttom it says UTF-8

Comment: The extension of your file should be `.ps1`. This doesn't have something to do with bash.

Comment: If UTF-8, that is UTF-8 with BOM (byte order mark). see [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) -- this will also prevent bash and sh from interpreting the file. If you plan on editing files that can be used with bash/sh,  you need to check the editor save settings and disable the BOM. You will also want to change the line-endings from DOS (`'\r\n'`) to Linux (`'\n'`). Powershell can read Linux line-endings, but bash and sh can't read DOS line endings. On Linux, you can use the `dos2unix` utility to convert the line endings automatically for you.

Comment: i am confused can my code be .sh and .ps1 or what should it be at first ? it work fine when i copy past on powershell so it's .ps1 right should i change it ?

Comment: @aze The code you gave above is not a shell script code regardless of the file format. Please try to research the basics.

Comment: The code you're showing in the question is PowerShell code not bash. The extension for a PowerShell script is `.ps1`. In addition you have 2 variables defined wrong `'$EmailTo` and `'$Subject`. Remove the `'` at the beginning of those variables.

Comment: Agree with Santiago, the *commenting* out of code is a *hashtag* (`#`) in powershell

Comment: i am sorry it was my mistake when i pasted here the code , the two ' are not included in my code

Comment: i changed the extension to .ps1 and executed the file with ./ test1.ps1 an error occured here At character C: \ Users \ IBrahimBoubaker \ Desktop \ test1.ps1: 8: 96
+ ... t System.Net.NetworkCredential (â € œdatastage.pvgtc@gmail.comâ €, â € rgœqvwjp ...
+ ~
Missing argument in the parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo: ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId: MissingArgument

Answer (score 1):

- **Save your PowerShell code in a file *with extension `.ps1`***, not `.sh`. This ensures that PowerShell knows that the file is a *PowerShell* script (see below).
- When you save the file, **use character encoding UTF-8 *with a BOM* to ensure that the [*Windows PowerShell* CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), `powershell.exe`, correctly interprets your script file** with respect to non-ASCII-range characters in the file, notably the quotation marks used in your code, `“` (LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK, [`U+201C`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c))

  - Using such *typographic* quotation marks - as opposed to the usual, ASCII-range quotation marks (`"` (QUOTATION MARK, [`U+0022`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22)) and `'` (APOSTROPHE, [`U+0027`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27)), used as a *single quote*) works fine in PowerShell, but only if the PowerShell engine recognizes the script file's actual character encoding; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55053609/45375) for more information.

---

**Background information**:

- You're running on *Windows*, where it is purely a script file's file-name *extension* - such as `.sh` - that determines what interpreter will execute it.

  - Using extension `.sh` is a(n ill-advised) *convention* in the *Unix* world indicating that a given file is a *shell script* designed to be interpreted by a POSIX-compatible shell, such as `/bin/sh`; however, unless the file is marked as executable via its file permissions *and* specifies the actual interpreter to use via a [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang%20%28Unix%29), you cannot invoke such files *directly*: you need to pass them to the target interpreter's executable as an argument.
  - On Windows, it is Git Bash, for instance, that registers extension `.sh` as to be executed with `bash`, which is why your attempt to invoke a `.sh` file resulted in a `bash` error message.
- Additionally, from inside PowerShell, `.ps1` files are run *in-process*, analogous to how batch files (`.cmd`, `.bat`) are run in-process from `cmd.exe`.