# Powershell positional parameter cannot be found

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Powershell.  When I run the following command from within a ps1 file:

```
add-computer -DomainName "example.com" -NewName "adfsserver" -restart
```

...I get this error:

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'example.com'
+ add-computer ?DomainName "example.com" -NewName "adfsserver" -restart
```

Interestingly, if I simply open a PowerShell window and paste this command in, it works fine (though it prompts me for credentials).

For me, a positional parameter is a parameter whose value is determined by its relative position in a parameter list.  I don't see that I'm using any positional parameters, I'm using named parameters (or named keys, whatever Powershell calls it).  According to the examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-computer?view=powershell-5.1) I'm using -DomainName correctly.  I can't tell it it is objecting to "-DomainName" or "example.com".

And for the life of me I don't understand why the command works perfectly fine when I type it in manually - does Windows have different PowerShell parsers that work differently in different places?

Comment: Make sure your dash is not an endash or emdash. The `?` indicates an unrecognized character, which is typical of ASCII and endash and emdash characters. You are likely copying from a location where visibly it is hard to tell a difference

Comment: In addition to @AdminOfThings helpful comment, you could use [`Splatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.1#:~:text=Splatting%20is%20a%20method%20of,collection%20with%20a%20command%20parameter.&text=Beginning%20in%20Windows%20PowerShell%203.0,all%20parameters%20of%20a%20command.) to avoid this kind of errors.

Answer (score 3):

As [AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings) points out, the `add-computer ?DomainName` part of your error message implies that the **`-` character in `-DomainName` was misinterpreted by PowerShell**, causing the token to be interpreted as a *positional argument* rather than a *parameter name*.

Therefore, the `example.com` argument became *another* - and therefore unrecognized - positional argument.

While using the ASCII-range `-` "dash" (strictly speaking: hyphen-minus, [`U+002D`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d)) is definitely preferable as the parameter-name sigil, PowerShell *does* accept non-ASCII variations such as `–` (en dash, [`U+2013`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013)), and when it doesn't, the implication is that *PowerShell is misinterpreting your source code*, something that is **fixed by re-saving your script with UTF-8 encoding *with a BOM*** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55053609/45375).