# Powershell Code from Script Runs Within a PowerShell ISE Session - The Script myscript.ps1 does not run from PS>myscript.ps1

Tags: powershell, db2

When I launch a powershell session via powershell.exe and at the PS> prompt enter myscript.ps1 it errors with -
PS D:\TEST> D:\TEST\testrun.ps1

Missing ')' in method call.

At D:\TEST\testrun.ps1:1 char:65

- $factory = [System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories]::GetFactory( <<<< â?oIBM.
  Data.DB2â??)

  - CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (CloseParenToken:TokenId) [], Parse
    Exception
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall

What is the reason for it working when running the lines of code individually via CutNPaste into ISE and launching?  I receive the email with a nice table from the db extraction when I run it via ISE. This error is probably why it doesn't run in TaskScheduler as well.

```
$factory = [System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories]::GetFactory(“IBM.Data.DB2”)
$cstrbld = $factory.CreateConnectionStringBuilder()
$cstrbld.Database = 'dbname'
$cstrbld.UserID = 'USER'
$cstrbld.Password = 'password'
$cstrbld.Server = 'server:50001'
$dbconn = $factory.CreateConnection()
$dbconn.ConnectionString = $cstrbld.ConnectionString
$dbconn.Open()
$dbcmd = $factory.CreateCommand()
$dbcmd.Connection = $dbconn
########################################################################################################################################
$dbcmd.CommandText = 'SELECT PFIWORKUNIT,ACTOR,FLOWDEFINITION,WORKTITLE,STATUS FROM APPLICATION.PFIWORKUNIT WHERE STATUS BETWEEN 0 AND 3'
########################################################################################################################################

$dbcmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text
$da = $factory.CreateDataAdapter()
$da.SelectCommand = $dbcmd
$ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$da.Fill($ds) | Out-Null

$dbconn.Close()
 
     ForEach ($row in $ds.Tables[0].Rows) {

        $ExciterObject = New-Object PSObject
        $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "PFIWORKUNIT" -Value $row.PFIWORKUNIT
        $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ACTOR" -Value $row.ACTOR 
        $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FLOWDEFINITION" -Value $row.FLOWDEFINITION 
        $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "WORKTITLE" -Value $row.WORKTITLE 
        $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "STATUS" -Value $row.STATUS
        $exportObject += $ExciterObject

        }

        
        function ConvertTo-HTMLTable ($obj) {
    # Accepts a System.Data.DataTable object or an array of PSObjects and converts to styled HTML table

    # add type needed to replace HTML special characters into entities
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

    $sb = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.StringBuilder
    [void]$sb.AppendLine('<table>')
    if ($null -ne $obj) {
        if (([object]$obj).GetType().FullName -eq 'System.Data.DataTable'){
            # it is a DataTable; convert to array of PSObjects
            $obj = $obj | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty ItemArray, Table, RowError, RowState, HasErrors
        }
        $headers = $obj[0].PSObject.Properties | Select -ExpandProperty Name
        [void]$sb.AppendLine('<thead><tr>')
        foreach ($column in $headers) {
            [void]$sb.AppendLine(('<th>{0}</th>' -f [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode($column)))
        }
        [void]$sb.AppendLine('</tr></thead><tbody>')
        $row = 0
        $obj | ForEach-Object {
            # add inline style for zebra color rows
            if ($row++ -band 1) {
                $tr = '<tr style="background-color: {0};">' -f $oddRowBackColor
            } 
            else {
                $tr = '<tr>'
            }
            [void]$sb.AppendLine($tr)
            foreach ($column in $headers) {
                [string]$val = $($_.$column)
                #If($NameAd -ne "")
                if ($val -notmatch "\S") { 
                    $td = '<td>&nbsp;</td>' 
                } 

                else { 
                    $td = '<td>{0}</td>' -f [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode($val)
                }
                [void]$sb.Append($td)
            }
            [void]$sb.AppendLine('</tr>')
        }

        [void]$sb.AppendLine('</tbody>')
    }
    [void]$sb.AppendLine('</table>')

    return $sb.ToString()
}


$headerBackColor = '#4F81BD'  # backgroundcolor for column headers
$oddRowBackColor = '#DCE6F1'  # background color for odd rows

$style = @"
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>Report</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="PowerShell" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Geneva, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: black;
    }

    table, td, th {
        border-color: black;
        border-style: solid;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Geneva, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
    }
    table {
        border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    td, th {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 4px;
        border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
        text-align: left;
    }
    th {
        color: white;
        background-color: $headerBackColor;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    </style>

<p><span style="color: #0000ff;"><strong>I'm only pulling only 1 thru 3 for a short email list</strong></span></p>
<p><span style="color: #0000ff;"><strong>WORK UNIT STATUS LEVELS BELOW:</strong></span></p>
<ol>
<li>01 = (<span style="color: #3366ff;"><strong>Ready for processing</strong></span>) using your SA account.</li>
<li>02 = (<span style="color: #3366ff;"><strong>Processing in progresst</strong></span>) using your SA account.</li>
<li>03 = (<span style="color: #3366ff;"><strong>Processing failed</strong></span>) using your SA account.</li>
<li>04 = (<span style="color: #3366ff;"><strong>Processing completed</strong></span>) using your SA account.</li>
<li>05 = (<span style="color: #3366ff;"><strong>Cancellation requested</strong></span>) using your SA account.</li>
<li>06 = (<span style="color: #3366ff;"><strong>Cancellation in progress</strong></span>) using your SA account.</li>
<li>07 = (<span style="color: #3366ff;"><strong>Cancellation failed</strong></span>) using your SA account.</li>
<li>08 = (<span style="color: #3366ff;"><strong>Cancellation completed</strong></span>) using your SA account.</li>
</ol>
"@
####SET EMAIL VALUES####
$bodyA = '{0}</head><body>{1}</body></html>' -f $style, (ConvertTo-HTMLTable $exportObject)
$EmailTo = "you@you.org"
$EmailFrom = "me@me.org"
$Subject = "Failed Work Unit Issue - High Priority" 
$Body = $bodyA 
$SMTPServer = "mail.server.org" 

####EMAIL PROCESS ####
$anonUsername = "anonymous"
$anonPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "anonymous" -AsPlainText -Force
$anonCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($anonUsername,$anonPassword)
Send-MailMessage -smtpserver "$SMTPServer" -from "$EmailFrom" -to "$EmailTo" -subject "$Subject" -bodyAsHtml "$Body" -credential $anonCredentials
Exit
```

Comment: Your script may be UTF-8-encoded but _without a BOM_, which causes Windows PowerShell to misinterpret it - try re-saving the script _with a BOM_ - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54790355/45375) for more information. If this solves your problem, we can mark your question as a duplicate of the linked post.

Comment: yes this was the issue of encoding.  I used Notepad ++ to resolve this by putting it in a UTF-8-BOM code

Answer (score -1):

The quotes in the below section aren't standard, so the compiler is interpreting them as other characters.

```
$factory = [System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories]::GetFactory(“IBM.Data.DB2”)
```

Note a regular ascii double quote is "034", but if you copy and paste one of the quote symbols from above into an [ascii converter](http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/ascii/) you'll get "226 128 156" as the ascii code instead.

TL;DR watch out for symbols that look a lot like the one you think you're using but aren't.

Comment: As since confirmed by the OP, the problem was one of _character encoding_ of the `.ps1` file. With character-encoding issues out of the way - perhaps surprisingly- PowerShell _does_ allow use of `“` (LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK, [`U+201C`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c)) in lieu of ASCII-range `"`, among other equivalents - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55053609/45375).