# Only Convert Valid Bytes with .NET GetBytes Method without creating question marks

Tags: .net, powershell, encoding

I am converting Strings with weird symbols I don't want into Latin-1 (or at least, what Microsoft made of it) and back into a string. I use PowerShell, but this is only about the .NET Methods:

```
    $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes($String)
    $String = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252).GetString($bytes)
```

This works pretty weird, except the weird symbols don't get removed, but question marks are created, for example:

> "Helloäöü?→"

becomes

> "Helloäöü?????"

What I want is to only convert valid bytes, without creating question marks, so the output will be:

> "Helloäöü?"

Is that possible?
I searched a bit already, but couldn't find anything. ChatGPT lies to me and says there would be a "GetValidBytes" method, but there isn't...

Comment: What is the original `$String` value? At least one example would be helpful :)

Comment: Something like `"Helloäöü?→" -replace '[^\x09-\x0D\x20-\xFF]'` perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a **[regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation based on [*named Unicode blocks*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#supported-named-blocks)**:

```bash
"Helloäöü€?→" -creplace '[^\p{IsBasicLatin}\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}–—€‚‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•˜™š›œžŸ]'
```

Given that your input already is a .NET string (and therefore composed of UTF-16 code units), there's no strict need for conversion to and from bytes:

- `\p{IsBasicLatin}` and `\p{IsLatin-1Supplement` matches characters that fall into the [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) Unicode *subrange*, which is *mostly* the same as [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), but is missing a few characters.
- The explicitly enumerated characters (`€...`) are those Windows-1252 characters *not* present in ISO-8859-1 (which therefore have different code points in Unicode than in Windows-1252, namely outside the 8-bit range).

  - `–` and `—` (en dash and em dash) are placed *first*, so that they aren't mistaken for describing a *range* of characters (the .NET regex engine apparently allows their interchangeable use with `-`, the regular "dash" (ASCII-range hyphen).
  - `‚` (single low-9 quotation mark) is *doubled* in order to *escape* it, because PowerShell allows its interchangeable use with `'` (single quotes) - see also: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55053609/45375) summarizes all such interchangeable uses allowed in PowerShell.

By replacing all *non*-matching (`^`) characters with the (implied) *empty string*, all non-Windows-1252 characters are effectively *removed*.

A general caveat:

- Due to the use of *literal* non-ASCII-range characters in the command, be sure that PowerShell interprets your script file's character encoding correctly, which notably means using UTF-8 files *with BOM* for the benefit of *Windows PowerShell* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54790355/45375).

---

However, **your to-and-from-bytes encoding approach *can* be used with a slight adaptation**, which **works with *any* target encoding** (without needing to enumerate individual characters, such as above):

Using a [`System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback) instance initialized with the *empty string* effectively removes all characters that cannot be represented in the target encoding.

```bash
$string = "Helloäöü€?→"

$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(
  1252,
  # Replace non-Windows-1252 chars. with '' (empty string), i.e. *remove* them.
  [System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback]::new(''),
  [System.Text.DecoderFallback]::ExceptionFallback # not relevant here
)

$string = $encoding.GetString($encoding.GetBytes($string))
```

Comment: This is a much more elegant solution.
Do you have a specific online ressource to recommend that shows the differences between all those encodings? 
Also, thanks for upvoting, I can finally comment now :D

Comment: @MySurmise, re up-voting privilege :) Please see my update re covering _all_ Windows-1252 characters. As for resources: Wikipedia is a good source; I've added a link to Wikipedia's Windows-1252 article to the answer.