# Code executed through Invoke-Command throws error

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

When I run

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize
```

directly from PowerShell, the code works just fine.

However, when I placed this exact code into file `script.txt` and then run

```
$stdout = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ([ScriptBlock]::Create((Get-Content 'script.txt'))) *>&1
```

I received the following error:

```
Exception calling "Create" with "1" argument(s): "At line:1 char:163
+ ... me, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize
+                                                                 ~~~~~~~~~
The string is missing the terminator: "."
```

What causes this behavior? How do I have to adjust the code to be able to execute the script from the external txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

The implication is that **you're using *Windows PowerShell* and that there is a *character-encoding problem***.
(The problem would *not* arise in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), whose consistent default encoding is now (BOM-less) UTF-8.)

You have two **solution options**:

- Either: Re-save your `script.txt` file as UTF-8 *with BOM*.
- Or: Use `-Encoding utf8` with your `Get-Content` call (note the bug alert below):

```bash
# Note the addition of -Encoding utf8.
# -Raw is added for robustness; it would be needed for *multiline* scripts.
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock (
   [ScriptBlock]::Create(
     (Get-Content -Encoding utf8 -Raw 'script.txt')
   )
 ) *>&1
```

A simpler alternative is to use `Invoke-Expression` (whose use is [generally best avoided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/avoid-using-invoke-expression), however):

```bash
Get-Content -Encoding utf8 -Raw 'script.txt' | Invoke-Expression *>&1
```

**Bug alert**:

When combining the above commends with redirection `*>&1`, *error* output, specifically, *disappears*, i.e. it unexpectedly isn't merged into the success [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) (`1`).

This applies to both *Windows PowerShell* (where it won't be fixed) and *PowerShell (Core)* up to at least v7.3.6; the relevant bug report is [GitHub issue #10476](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10476).

A **workaround** is to enclose the `Invoke-Command` call or the `Invoke-Expression` pipeline in `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) before applying `*>&1`, e.g.:

```bash
# Note the (...), which has side effects, however.
(Get-Content -Encoding utf8 -Raw 'script.txt' | Invoke-Expression) *>&1
```

The workaround has a **side effect**: Using `(...)` means that all output from the enclosed command is *collected in memory first, in full*, before the redirection is applied and output is produced.

---

###### Background information:

- It looks like your `script.txt` is UTF-8-encoded *but lacks a BOM*, which causes *Windows PowerShell* to misinterpret your file as ANSI-encoded (i.e., using the single-byte ANSI code page of your system's legacy locale).
- It isn't obvious but your file contains a non-ASCII-range character:

  - The `–` in `–AutoSize` is the EN DASH, [`U+2013`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013) character, not the usual ASCII-range `-`, `-` (HYPHEN-MINUS, [`U+002D`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d)) character.
  - When the 3-byte UTF-8 encoding of `–` is misinterpreted as ANSI, each byte becomes a character in its own right, specifically: `â€“`

It is the `“` (LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK, [`U+201C`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c)) - which PowerShell accepts as an alternative to the usual ASCII-range double quote, QUOTATION MARK, [`U+0022`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22) - that causes the syntax error, because a *closing* double quote is missing.

Similarly, PowerShell accepts  `-` (EN DASH) in lieu of the ASCII-range `-`.

For the complete list of interchangeable quotation and punctuation characters with syntactic function supported by PowerShell, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55053609/45375).

However, for robustness it is generally better to use the ASCII-range characters.

The remedies in the top section avoid the problem.

Comment: Amazing detailed answer. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't `$stdout = Invoke-Command ... *>&1` save both STDOUT **and** STDERR into variable? Why the error output disappeared? How can I prevent such behavior? I want to collect and combine ALL outputs. Please advise.

Comment: The bug reported ~4 years ago, still not fixed? Wow! That is a huge disappointment.

Comment: @Ωmega, I agree that it's frustrating. I've added a workaround to the answer, but note its side effects.

Comment: Your workaround excludes important switches/parameters **-Encoding utf8 -Raw** you suggested using in the first place.

Comment: To clear the “side effect” of your workaround – does that mean that I will not lose any part of the STDOUT and/or STDERR outputs, but lines may be in wrong orders? What such collecting in memory exactly causes?

Comment: @Ωmega, no, it doesn't, but it only spells out the simpler `Invoke-Expression` solution; you can use `(...)` analogously with your `Invoke-Command` approach, if you prefer. I originally thought that only `Invoke-Expression` was affected by the bug, but as you've discovered `Invoke-Command` is affected too.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't refresh the page to see your last update. My bad.

Comment: @Ωmega, no, you won't lose information, and the output objects will be in the correct order. `(...)` can increase memory consumption, and it affects output _timing_. If neither is a concern, you should be good.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Ωmega. To illustrate the output-timing issue: compare `Invoke-Command { 1..3 | % { $_; pause } }` to `(Invoke-Command { 1..3 | % { $_; pause } })`

Comment: If you don't mind, there is one more issue. The output received when the code is run directly and via `Invoke-Expression` is not the same. Please check https://justpaste.it/c28yq to see two outputs I am getting. Any idea why and how to fix it? THANKS!

Comment: @Ωmega Remove the Format-* command, that's only for console output. You don't want to pass format data on to other commands/pipeline